# Change value in an observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

If I have an observable `student: Observable<Student>` where `Student` has the parameter `name: string` is set to `Jim`, How can I change the value of `name` in the `students` observable to be `Bob`?

Edit:

Is `student.map(student => student.name = 'Bob')` supposed to work. Because if yes then there is something else wrong with my program.

Comment: That's what `map` is for

Comment: `student.map(student => ({...student, name: 'Bob'}))`

Comment: @ZahiC I don't understand your answer... with larger objects would I have to enter values for every parameter? What if I just want to change one? is `...` part of the syntax or is that a place holder for something else?

Comment: @ZahiC has the correct answer, assuming you are using new enough versions of TypeScript / JavaScript.

Comment: Best practice with map is not to change existing objects, but create a new copy (immutability). `{...student, name: 'Bob'}` is the new syntax for Object.assign, meaning, copy all the properties from `student` and override the `name` property with the value `'Bob'`

Comment: How new? I'm using Typescript 2.2.2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@ZahiC's answer is the right one, but let me explain a little bit why.

First, with Rxjs, the less side effects you have, the better.
Immutability is your friend! Otherwise, when your app will grow, it's going to be a nightmare trying to guess where an object has been mutated.

Second, since [Typescript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html) you can use the object spread. Which means that to update a student object, instead of doing:

```
const newStudent = Object.assign({}, oldStudent, {name: 'new student name'});
```

You can do:

```
const newStudent = {...oldStudent, name: 'new student name'};
```

In both case, you're not mutating the original student, but rather creating a new one with an updated value.

Last thing, is how to combine that with Rxjs.
The `map` operator is here for that: Take a value, do what you want with it and return a new one which is going to be used down the observable chain.

So, instead of:

```
student.map(student => student.name = 'Bob');
```

You should do (as @ZahiC pointed out):

```
student.map(student => ({...student, name: 'Bob'}));
```

And in order to avoid shadowing variable name, you might also want to call your observable: `student$`

```
student$.map(student => ({...student, name: 'Bob'}));
```

**EDIT:**
Since Rxjs 5.5 you should not use operators patched on Observable.prototype and use the pipe operator instead:

```
student$.pipe(
  map(student => ({...student, name: 'Bob'})),
  tap(student => console.log(student)) // will display the new student 
)
```

Comment: One note, the `map` function is declared in `'rxjs/operators'`.

Comment: If anyone is wondering why the tap in the above example doesn't fire it's because you have to subscribe to it.

Comment: Oh yes I could have been more precise and explain that you have to subscribe to it but it's also one of the first thing you learn with observables. @Mickers if you want to know more about that google cold vs host observables :)