# Modifying a property on every emitted value in an observable based on another property

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to set a boolean property on every value emitted by an observable by checking if all three level nested items are set to true, using map.
More specific: If all matches in all pools are finished, I want to set property "poolsFinished" to true on the competition.

I found this example: [Change value in an observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783266/change-value-in-an-observable][1])
but it's not working for me.

All I get as an error is "Server returned code: undefined".

What am I not understanding?

```
getCompetitionPopulated(id: number): Observable<ICompetition> {
    var response = this._http.get<ICompetition>(environment.apiUrl + '/competition/' + id + '/pool/fencer')
    .pipe(
      map(comp => ({...comp, poolsFinished: comp.pools.every(p => p.matches.every(m => m.finished))})),
      catchError(this.handleError));

    return response;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Server returned code: undefined` would indicate some error with your server. Are you sure your server works ok?

Comment: It looks like your GET request returns no data. Please confirm in the network tab of your browser inspector that the request returns valid data.